# Simple table normalisation

Tags: database-design, normalization

In raw form, I have data with  2 columns: `skills in welsh` and `stats for that skill`. For storing these information in a database, would it be best to combine the stats with the categories, or split them up as below?

```
WELSH_SKILLS_TABLE
----------------------------------------------------
|  SKILL_ID   |                SKILL
----------------------------------------------------
|      0      |            CAN'T SPEAK
----------------------------------------------------


WELSH_STATS_TABLE
----------------------------------------------------
|  SKILL_FK   |                COUNT
----------------------------------------------------
|      0      |                 235
----------------------------------------------------
```

Instinctively, the laid out method seems to be correct, but for such a simple task, also seems like overkill?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing anything else about your system, that seems like total overkill.  You'd be better off with a single table that has `ID`, `Skill`, and `SkillCount`.

Having two tables for such a simple schema will result in unnecessary work for both the DBA and developer.  The database engine will need to perform extra work to `JOIN` the two tables whenever you require reading both `Skill` and `SkillCount` at the same time.

If you had a really, really large dataset (think hundreds of millions or billions of rows) and you regularly needed to access just the `Skill` and rarely needed to show the `SkillCount` field, then perhaps you might consider using your design.

Answer (score 4):

You ask about normalization.

If you start with this

```
skill        count
--
Can't speak  235
...
```

it should be clear that the only candidate key is "skill". This relation is in 5NF.

There is no normalization guideline that introduces new columns like "skill_id". (There's no such thing as "now I have an ID number" normal form.)

Comment: +1.  I added the ID field since I assume (we both know where that goes!) the system will need the ability to join this table with other data, and in a big enough set of data, an INT field is far more efficient for joins than a string-based field.

Comment: Have you measured the efficiency?  (I have. You'll probably be surprised.)

Comment: I have not measured it.  I guess the level of difference would vary dramatically with the length of the natural keys.  I'd be very interested in hearing about your results - do you have a blog entry somewhere or something?

Comment: @MaxVernon Your assumption was correct, I do need to connect this data with approximately 3 million rows, so I'm using a "char" (note the quotes) as a lightweight and fast index to the data. But again,I'd be interested in the same insight that Mike has. Thanks again.

Comment: I've written about it here and on SO. Think about a "lookup" table--one column of data and an id number. Now drop the id number, write foreign keys to reference the data, and you avoid a join altogether. With other tables, you avoid a join every time the data you need is in a referenced key. (I was surprised how often this happens.)  The tradeoff is between join performance and disk I/O. Prototypes indicated that natural keys would perform better in the test suite (dozens of queries) for decades without improvements in hardware (like SSDs).

Comment: I just posted a question with data from my tests.  Perhaps you could chime in on what I'm doing wrong, since my tests show INT keys to be 3 times faster than string-based keys for joins.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50708/do-natural-keys-provide-higher-or-lower-performance-in-sql-server-than-surrogate