# What is the advantages of using auto_increment in database as primary key over set of attributes?

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

I have table as

```
CREATE TABLE circle
(
    circle_id int(11) auto_increment primary key not null,
    user_id int (11) not null,
    title varchar(255) collate  utf8_general_ci not null
);


CREATE TABLE circle_share1
(
    id int(11) auto_increment primary key not null,
    circle_id int(11),
    user_id int(11),
    start_time date
);


CREATE TABLE circle_share2
(
    circle_id int(11),
    user_id int(11),
    start_time date,
    primary key(circle_id , user_id)
);
```

What are the advantages of using table share1 over share2 ?

```
share2 has primary key of circle_id , user_id 

and share1 has primary key id .
```

I checked 50 tables out of them none of the table is like share2  , Why developers are not preferred  share2 ?

Comment: What you're looking for is a definitive answer to the long-standing debate between using a surrogate key (`circle`/`circle_share1`) or the natural key (`circle_share2`). different dbms' may handle them differently. here's some more information for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/63090/251174

Comment: Here is another question I wrote about the subject that has some interesting answers.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50708/do-natural-keys-provide-higher-or-lower-performance-in-sql-server-than-surrogate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`circle_share1` does not require much in-depth design thought.  `circle_share2` requires some actual brain cycles to determine if the primary key will have the desired performance.

Rows in `circle_share1` will be written to the disk in the exact order they are inserted, thereby making inserts quicker.

Rows in `circle_share2` *may* be inserted anywhere in the table, necessitating page-splits thereby fragmenting the data and possibly resulting in slower performance.

Neither way is the **correct** way in **all** circumstances - the *best* way depends on your data, and how it will be created in the `user` and `circle` tables and inserted into the `circle_shareX` table.

Comment: I have **thousands or millions**  of tupples in **circle_shareX** as well as **circle** and  data is inserted in the tables frequently like social networking site . In this scenario Which one is best  choice based on performance .

Comment: Without *me* placing all that much thought into *your* situation, it is likely that placing the primary key on the `auto_increment` field would be better.  It would certainly be faster for inserts on the `circle_shareX` table.