# Should I Use a Composite Key or a Single-Column Primary Key in my Entity Relationship Diagram?

Tags: database-design, primary-key, erd

I am designing an Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) for a database that includes a table with variants annotated by different tools. In this table, each variant is annotated by a specific tool, and the combination of the tool and the variant uniquely identifies each row.

The table currently has two columns: database_tool and variantID. I am considering two approaches to define the primary key for this table:

**Composite Key Approach**: Using both database_tool and variantID as a composite primary key.

**Single-Column Key Approach**: Creating a new column, say database_tool_variantID, and using it as a single-column primary key.

I am seeking advice on which approach might be more beneficial for my database design. Are there specific advantages or potential pitfalls that I should be aware of with either approach, particularly in terms of query efficiency, database maintenance, and scalability?

Any insights or experiences with similar scenarios would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unclear. Does this table stores `tool_id` which refers on `id` in `tools` table, and `variant_id` which refers on `id` in `variants` table? If so then PK `(tool_id, variant_id)` + regular `(variant_id, tool_id)` seems to be reasonable. But this depends on DBMS - for example, in MySQL the primary key is clustered one unconditionally, so backward variant or even synthetic PK + unique (one of above) + regular (naother one) may be more reasonable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Surrogate key vs Natural key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184403/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key)

Answer (score 0):

> Are there specific advantages or potential pitfalls that I should be aware of with either approach...

Depends on how your system operates.

One generically true potential pitfall of a composite key with *meaningful* values such as `database_tool`, is the risk of that value changing. Perhaps `database_tool` has a value one day called `Saw` and a year later that value needs to be renamed to `Table Saw`. This causes 2 problems:

1. Once you rename that value in the source `database_tools` table, the combination table with variants will be immediately compromised from a data integrity perspective (and anywhere else that key value was being referenced).
2. To fix said data integrity issues, you'd have to update every reference to the old value of `Saw` in every table referencing it. This is not necessarily a performant way to go about things.

Of course this entirely depends on if such a scenario is possible and is why immutability is a good property to consider when choosing a primary key. If instead, you had a single table of `database_tools` that had a unique `ID` value that was part of the composite key, then that would avoid the above scenario when the value needed to change.