# Determinism inside an INSTEAD OF trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger, referential-integrity

In reference to my prior question about a [preferred design to avoid circular or multiple update path](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184832/preferred-design-to-avoid-circular-multiple-update-paths) referential integrity cascading updates and deletes via `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`, I'm attempting to use a trigger as an alternative.

For this example, I've attempted to simplify the design as much as possible.

I have a `Parent` table and a `Child` table; `Parent` and `Child` share a column, `ParentName`.  Whenever `Parent.ParentName` changes, I want to reflect that change in `Child.ParentName`.

Simple enough?  If I update a single row in `Parent`, I can use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables to very easily know which row to update in both the `Parent` and `Child` tables.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE Parent
SET Parent.ParentName = inserted.ParentName
FROM Parent
    INNER JOIN deleted ON Parent.ParentName = deleted.ParentName
    CROSS JOIN inserted;

UPDATE Child
SET Child.ParentName = inserted.ParentName
FROM Child
    INNER JOIN deleted ON Child.ParentName = deleted.ParentName
    CROSS JOIN inserted;
```

Pretty clearly, this won't work if more than a single row in `Parent` is modified in one `UPDATE` statement.

The tables:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Parent', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Parent;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Parent
(
    ParentName int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY
    , IsActive bit NOT NULL
);

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Child', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Child;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Child
(
    ChildName int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY
    , ParentName int NOT NULL
    , IsActive bit NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Parent (ParentName, IsActive)
VALUES (0, 1)
    , (1, 1)
    , (2, 1);

INSERT INTO dbo.Child (ChildName, ParentName, IsActive)
VALUES (7, 0, 1)
    , (8, 1, 1)
    , (9, 2, 1);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Parent;
```

```
╔════════════╦══════════╗
║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠════════════╬══════════╣
║ 0          ║ 1        ║
║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 2          ║ 1        ║
╚════════════╩══════════╝
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Child;
```

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ ChildName ║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ 7         ║ 0          ║ 1        ║
║ 8         ║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 9         ║ 2          ║ 1        ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DRI
ON dbo.Parent
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Parent
    SET Parent.ParentName = inserted.ParentName
    FROM Parent
        INNER JOIN deleted ON Parent.ParentName = deleted.ParentName
        CROSS JOIN inserted;

    UPDATE Child
    SET Child.ParentName = inserted.ParentName
    FROM Child
        INNER JOIN deleted ON Child.ParentName = deleted.ParentName
        CROSS JOIN inserted;
END
GO
```

Testing it:

```
UPDATE dbo.Parent SET ParentName = 6 WHERE ParentName = 2;
```

The results:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Parent;
```

```
╔════════════╦══════════╗
║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠════════════╬══════════╣
║ 0          ║ 1        ║
║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 6          ║ 1        ║  <-- this row has changed
╚════════════╩══════════╝
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Child;
```

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ ChildName ║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ 7         ║ 0          ║ 1        ║
║ 8         ║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 9         ║ 6          ║ 1        ║  <-- this row has changed
╚═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

If, however I update multiple rows, you get this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Parent SET ParentName = ParentName + 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Parent;
```

```
╔════════════╦══════════╗
║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠════════════╬══════════╣
║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 1          ║ 1        ║
╚════════════╩══════════╝
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Child;
```

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ ChildName ║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ 7         ║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 8         ║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 9         ║ 1          ║ 1        ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

I could resolve this by making the trigger refuse updates where there are more than a single row being updated, however that's not very scalable, and will promote RBAR.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DRI
ON dbo.Parent
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @msg nvarchar(1000);
    SET @msg = 'Only a single row can be updated per batch.';
    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM inserted) > 1 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR (@msg, 10, 1);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Parent
        SET Parent.ParentName = inserted.ParentName
        FROM Parent
            INNER JOIN deleted ON Parent.ParentName = deleted.ParentName
            CROSS JOIN inserted;

        UPDATE Child
        SET Child.ParentName = inserted.ParentName
        FROM Child
            INNER JOIN deleted ON Child.ParentName = deleted.ParentName
            CROSS JOIN inserted;
    END
END
GO
```

Is there something I can do to mitigate this?  Obviously, I don't want to add an `IDENTITY` column to these tables, since that will negate the purpose of using natural keys.

I thought about using `ROW_NUMBER()` in the trigger as a sort of pseudo-column on the `inserted` and `deleted` tables; however I cannot use a "proper" `ORDER BY` in the `OVER(...)` clause, which makes the row numbers non-deterministic:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DRI
ON dbo.Parent
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH i AS (
        SELECT *
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        FROM inserted
        )
    , d AS (
        SELECT *
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        FROM deleted
        )
    UPDATE dbo.Parent
    SET Parent.ParentName = i.ParentName
    FROM i
        INNER JOIN d ON i.rn = d.rn
    WHERE Parent.ParentName = d.ParentName

    ;WITH i AS (
        SELECT *
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        FROM inserted
        )
    , d AS (
        SELECT *
            , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
        FROM deleted
        )
    UPDATE dbo.Child
    SET Child.ParentName = i.ParentName
    FROM i
        INNER JOIN d ON i.rn = d.rn
    WHERE Child.ParentName = d.ParentName
END
GO
```

The test:

```
UPDATE dbo.Parent SET ParentName = ParentName + 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Parent;
```

```
╔════════════╦══════════╗
║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠════════════╬══════════╣
║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 2          ║ 1        ║
║ 3          ║ 1        ║
╚════════════╩══════════╝
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Child;
```

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ ChildName ║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ 7         ║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 8         ║ 2          ║ 1        ║
║ 9         ║ 3          ║ 1        ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

This *does* appear to solve the problem, but I'm concerned it is not reliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought about using `ROW_NUMBER()` in the trigger as a sort of pseudo-column...

Stop thinking this. There is no guarantee of row order in the *inserted* or *deleted* pseudo-tables. You may observe it "working", but you will be relying on undocumented behaviour.

The standard workaround for the lack of an exposed unique row identifier to correlate updated rows (or an *updated* pseudo-table, or per-row triggers...etc.) is to add an **immutable** alternate key, such as a column with the `IDENTITY` property. I realize this goes against the design objective of the question, but that does not change the facts.

A `rowversion` column would work as well, but that is 8 bytes and rather a misuse.

Connect items:

- [Add row identifiers to trigger tables INSERTED and DELETED](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/125339/add-row-identifiers-to-trigger-tables-inserted-and-deleted) (Won't Fix)
- [Improve inserted/deleted table joining in triggers](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/741799/improve-inserted-deleted-table-joining-in-triggers) (Won't Fix)

Answer (score 2):

I've added a `rowversion` column to my `Parent` table, and replaced the `ROW_NUMBER()` functionality in the trigger with that column.

I like the `rowversion` for this demo-code since it operates similarly to an `IDENTITY()` without looking suspiciously similar to a surrogate key.  I realize `IDENTITY()` and surrogate keys are two completely separate concepts, however `IDENTITY()` is very commonly used as the default value for a surrogate primary key.

Since the database-wide `rowversion` number is updated *every* time a DML statement is executed, there should be virtually no additional overhead associated with adding that column to the table, aside from storage space, which I'm happy with for this demo.

Anyway, the new code looks like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Parent', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Parent;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Parent
(
    ParentName int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY
    , rv rowversion
    , IsActive bit NOT NULL
);

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Child', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Child;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Child
(
    ChildName int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY
    , ParentName int NOT NULL
    , IsActive bit NOT NULL
);

GO
CREATE TRIGGER DRI
ON dbo.Parent
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH i AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM inserted
        )
    , d AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM deleted
        )
    UPDATE dbo.Parent
    SET Parent.ParentName = i.ParentName
    FROM i
        INNER JOIN d ON i.rv = d.rv
    WHERE Parent.ParentName = d.ParentName

    ;WITH i AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM inserted
        )
    , d AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM deleted
        )
    UPDATE dbo.Child
    SET Child.ParentName = i.ParentName
    FROM i
        INNER JOIN d ON i.rv = d.rv
    WHERE Child.ParentName = d.ParentName
END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Parent (ParentName, IsActive)
VALUES (0, 1)
    , (1, 1)
    , (2, 1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Child (ChildName, ParentName, IsActive)
VALUES (7, 0, 1)
    , (8, 1, 1)
    , (9, 2, 1);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Parent;
```

```
╔════════════╦════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ ParentName ║ rv                 ║ IsActive ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 1          ║ 0x00000000000007D4 ║ 1        ║
║ 2          ║ 0x00000000000007D5 ║ 1        ║
║ 3          ║ 0x00000000000007D6 ║ 1        ║
╚════════════╩════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Child;
```

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ ChildName ║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ 7         ║ 1          ║ 1        ║
║ 8         ║ 2          ║ 1        ║
║ 9         ║ 3          ║ 1        ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

```
UPDATE dbo.Parent SET ParentName = ParentName + 1;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Parent;
```

```
╔════════════╦════════════════════╦══════════╗
║ ParentName ║ rv                 ║ IsActive ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════╬══════════╣
║ 2          ║ 0x00000000000007D9 ║ 1        ║
║ 3          ║ 0x00000000000007DA ║ 1        ║
║ 4          ║ 0x00000000000007DB ║ 1        ║
╚════════════╩════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Child;
```

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ ChildName ║ ParentName ║ IsActive ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ 7         ║ 2          ║ 1        ║
║ 8         ║ 3          ║ 1        ║
║ 9         ║ 4          ║ 1        ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is it necessary to utilize Cascading RI?  I've always found it to be much more troublesome than it's worth.

Since you're already customizing a solution, I think the easiest approach would be adding a second *PKEY* column that you can reference in the `deleted` and `inserted` tables within the trigger.

So your Parent Table DDL would now look like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Parent', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Parent;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Parent
(
    ParentName int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY
    , PKEY2 int NOT NULL
    , IsActive bit NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Parent (ParentName, PKEY2, IsActive)
VALUES (0, 0, 1)
    , (1, 1, 1)
    , (2, 2, 1);
```

Your trigger can then update the PKEY2 column on the Parent table as part of the updates made after the child table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Parent_Trigger
ON dbo.Parent
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() <= 1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Child
        SET Child.ParentName = inserted.ParentName
        FROM dbo.Child Child INNER JOIN inserted ON Child.ParentName = inserted.PKEY2

        UPDATE Parent
        SET Parent.ParentName = inserted.ParentName,
            Parent.PKEY2 = inserted.ParentName
        FROM dbo.Parent Parent INNER JOIN inserted on Parent.PKEY2 = inserted.PKEY2
    END
END
GO
```

You have to deal with the extra column, but it should perform well with proper indexing in place.